# Mssql Insert multiple raw with same id from other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Hello i have a matter with an insert query ill try to explain bellow :

Here is a simplify view of my tables 
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTjjj.png)

Table A                  Table B 
ID / Number        ID
1  / 0               1
1  / 1               2
1  / 2               3
2  / 0               4
2  / 1               5
2  / 2               6
3  / 0               7
3  / 1               8
3  / 2               9

so i already have my query who select the id of table B not inside table A

I want to insert them in Table A but as you can see i need to insert them 3 time and after the first insert my query dont work anymore.

What is the best way to do this? Create a view? a tamporary table? or multiple query?

So thx to all who have answer here is the solution i used to achieve the matter:

```
//Here i get the Missing ID and put them inside temp Table
select ID into #temp_id from TableA rv left outer join TableB lrva on
rv.ID = lrva.ID where 'other Table B attribut'  is null

//Then i insert the values
insert into TableA select ID, 1 from #temp_id;
insert into TableA select ID, 2 from #temp_id;
insert into TableA select ID, 3 from #temp_id;

//Then destroy the temp table
Drop Table #temp_id
```

Keep in mind that i need specific treatment for the Number column as for other column i dont name on the exemple that s why i cant just do a +1 or things like this. The meaning of the question was just how to insert in the easyest way multiple id from other table, and not really how to achieve this in the exemple who as simple data.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Some of us can't even see the images...)

Comment: Please post the expected sample output.

Comment: Please check the answer below, I hope the single query will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this works:

```
CREATE table TABLEA(id int, [number] int)
CREATE table TABLEB (id int)
insert into TABLEA values (1,  0 )
insert into TABLEA values (1,  1 )
insert into TABLEA values (1,  2 )
insert into TABLEA values (2,  0 )
insert into TABLEA values (2,  1 )
insert into TABLEA values (2,  2 )
insert into TABLEA values (3,  0 )
insert into TABLEA values (3,  1 )
insert into TABLEA values (3,  2 )

insert into TABLEB values (1)
insert into TABLEB values (2)
insert into TABLEB values (3)
insert into TABLEB values (4)
insert into TABLEB values (5)
insert into TABLEB values (6)
insert into TABLEB values (7)
insert into TABLEB values (8)
insert into TABLEB values (9)

DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
select 'INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES ('+convert(char,id)+',0),('+convert(char,id)+',1),('+convert(char,id)+',2)' from TABLEB where id not in (select id from TABLEA)
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @QUERY
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
EXEC (@QUERY)
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @QUERY
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C

SELECT * FROM TABLEA

id          number
----------- -----------
1           0
1           1
1           2
2           0
2           1
2           2
3           0
3           1
3           2
4           0
4           1
4           2
5           0
5           1
5           2
6           0
6           1
6           2
7           0
7           1
7           2
8           0
8           1
8           2
9           0
9           1
9           2
```

Comment: You just let me the time to edit my question and you already got the answer. At least you got the right expected output but i dont understand the process you use.  What is '+convert(char,id)+' use for ? and what do your cursor ?

Comment: since 'insert into ' => this is varchar and as i have careated id as int. so to combine them , i just converted id to char

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**: this will give you what you want, it will give produce Cartesian value exactly as your requirement and you can add condition by using `WHERE` to limit data:

```
create table #tableA(id int, number int)
create table #tableB(id int)

insert into #tableB values
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),
(7),(8),(9)

insert into #tableA
select t.id, number
from (values(0),(1),(2)) x (number)
cross apply(select id from #tableB) t
where not exists(select 1 from #tableA A where A.id = t.id)
```

**OUTPUT**
    --select * from #tableA

```
id  number
1   0
1   1
1   2
2   0
2   1
2   2
3   0
3   1
3   2
--so on for each ids...
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, i test it but dont have the same output. I have only 1 time each id and with 0 for each values of number

Comment: Isn't that your desired output, that I have posted in `OUTPUT` ? if so please check it properly

Comment: Yes thats the output i need after a select * Table A after having insert missing IDs present inside Table B

Comment: Its really terrible, please try the full updated answer.

Comment: Nice of you to answer but even if i am not so good in sql i know how to insert by a simple select and 1 more thing i wont use a solution that  dont understand the process. So explain more and i can use what you say because if you read more my question its a simplify illustration of what i want to do and i dont want to insert all id but only the missing one.

Comment: Updated, I have used `NOT EXISTS` to avoid the `Records or IDs` that are already exist in the `#tableA`.